# How do I install company-mode via `ensure-packages-installed`?

Tags: company-mode, package-repositories

I use a function, `ensure-packages-installed` to "bootstrap" packages in my `.emacs` file. This ensures that if the package isn't already install. The follow is at the top of my `.emacs`:

```
;
; Set up Emacs package system.
;
(require 'package)
;(add-to-list 'package-archives
;             '("elpa" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
;(add-to-list 'package-archives
;             '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

; fetch the list of packages available
(or (file-exists-p package-user-dir)
  (package-refresh-contents))

(defun ensure-packages-installed (&rest packages)
  (mapcar (lambda (package)
    (unless (package-installed-p package)
      (package-install package))) packages))

(ensure-packages-installed
  'company-mode
  'exec-path-from-shell
  'evil
  'haskell-mode
  'intero
  'idris-mode
  'org
  'projectile
  'solarized-theme
  )
```

However, when I add `company-mode` to the list it, I get the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/steshaw/.emacs':

error: Package `company-mode-' is unavailable

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Comment: Is the package name `company-mode` or just `company`?

Comment: Yes, `company` seems to work. It's not mentioned on their website AFAICS. Is this a common emacs package naming convention? i.e. <package> for the package and `<package>-mode` for the function to enable the package?

Comment: Yes I think `package` is the standard based on examples I read on how to set buffer mode using local variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `company` instead of `company-mode`.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Dan. As far as I can work out, it's rather strange to name the package in this way. Quite unfortunate and not mentioned on their website :(. BTW, I used to love Scheme and Common Lisp (because it was fast) but I'd recommend taking a leap into Haskell and Idris. I think you'd enjoy the ride!

Comment: @StevenShaw: no worries.  I don't use `company`, but I agree that it's a little odd that it wouldn't be `company-mode` in this setting.  I updated this post because Community was flagging it as low quality due to length.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm only just getting a taste of how Stackexchange works behind the scenes. It doesn't seem to be all good.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `use-package`. It would look like:

`(use-package company :ensure t :pin melpa)`

Comment: Does `use-package` replace my "custom" (aka copied from the interwebs) `ensure-packages-installed`? I figure that's what `:ensure t` does. What's `:pin melpa` for?

Comment: It specifies the repository from which you want to download the package. But you can do far more with use-package. Take a look at https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package.

Comment: Oh thanks, that does look nice. The missing packager (aka package management system) that I've been looking for! I felt kind of dirty having a half-baked packager in my `~/.emacs`. Any more tips to modernise my Emacs usage? I'm considering a complete jump to Spacemacs. Just installed it today. Seems very well thought out so far.

Comment: I don't know anything about spacemacs. However in terms of organizing your .emacs you should try an org-mode based config. Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIuOwIBL-ZU.